# Can I still work on C Project with OpenGL using gcc under macOS Mojave?

Tags: c, macos, opengl, gcc

I read that macOS Mojave does not support OpenGL anymore. I have to make a small C project for University with OpenGL using gcc.

Does macOS Mojave not supporting OpenGL anymore mean that I wont be able to compile such files anymore under macOS? Or will it still be possible?
Or do I have to install Linux / Windows for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL does still work, and can be compiled against, under Mojave (i.e. the OpenGL.framework is still in System/Library/Frameworks, and you can select the framework in in Xcode for development).

However, Apple announced that it is deprecated from now on. This means that it might be removed in any later version and limited development will go into it (i.e. don't expect bug fixes any more).

Comment: @AlexanderLöffler: For long-term projects I'd look into MoltenVK (Vulkan on top of Metal) and Zink (OpenGL on top of Vulkan); maybe stacking them on each other is a good mid-term bypass. There's also MoltenGL, but that's only OpenGL-ES and a commercial product.